# Why Bootstrap 4 carousel auto crop image in height?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm use Bootstrap 4 carousel, and I need the carousel show the full height of image .

I do not know why boostrap is cuting it in height

The dimensions are 1920 x 700 and the carousel adjust the image 1900 x 595

I see the same image in curvy-slider (wordpress) and this plugin dont' do this.

```
<div id="carousel-area">
    <div id="carousel-slider" class=" slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="/data/1.jpg" alt="" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some one can helpe me?

Comment: Please see this link and update your question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Without the code nobody can help

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap should accommodate varying heights of images unless there is a specific height been set somewhere for the carousel.

```
#myCarousel img {
  width: auto;
  height: 225px;
  max-height: 225px;
}
```

from:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2413998

you can see here to :

https://bootstrapcreative.com/create-full-width-bootstrap-4-responsive-carousel/

Comment: The second link is very helpful, thank you very much!